# What are the shaving options for the carry-on traveler?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage, cold-weapons

*This question rustled some jimmies! Now that we have more information I'm rephrasing it to fit in better with the overall picture, which is shaving options for travelers without checked luggage.*

---

When traveling with carry-on luggage only, it's not always obvious what shaving equipment we can bring on a plane.
For those of us that shave with open-ended blades such as double-edged safety razors or straight razors, as opposed to disposable and cartridge razors, the problem is exacerbated by trips with multiple stops where we have to tediously acquire blades at every destination.

Naturally, the most flagrant razor blades are not permitted on a plane, but some shaving equipment is. As a not-too-frequent traveler myself I've never quite really gotten a hang on this, and I end up chasing down razor blades at a kiosk in some far away place at 2AM.

There must be a better way! I figure frequent/business travelers must have developed several best practices of dealing with shaving by now.

From the perspective of someone who most certainly cannot bring their regular razor onto the plane, what options are there for a traveler limited to carry-on luggage only?

Comment: "Those of us that shave" - huh? Nope, you mean "those of us that shave with an open blade or cutthroat razor" surely? I just got off a flight from New Zealand to the UK and was *handed* disposable razors onboard as part of the amenities kits, I went through security at two places with Gillette razors in my carry on with no issues at all.  I've *never* had issues at an airport with a razor.

Comment: I never had problems with my cartridge razors in myhand luggage.

Comment: @Moo I wasn't aware that disposable/cartridge razors were **universally** permitted in carry-on, but yes; I use double-edged safety razors.

Comment: Get a Philips OneBlade. You'll never go back to regular shaving again.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is a route I'm sure we don't want to go down. :) Thanks for updating the title. Feel free to edit the question as appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanReez I use a safety razor, so if I don't check a bag, I mail blades ahead (you can mail a few taped down to a piece of paper, in their paper wrapping for safety, for first-class postage).  Just address it to Jonathan Reez (Arriving Nov. 25), c/o Hotel Lovely, ...

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, Caterpillar: I usually use a double-edged safety razor, but I have some disposables that I take with me when I'm flying without checked bags.  I find that using different blades from time to time provides refreshing variety.  The double-edged blades are very inexpensive, which is one reason I like to use them, but it can be difficult to find a place that sells them, so I don't want to spend time doing that while I'm traveling.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16917/19400

Comment: This is a reminder that we close duplicate *questions* and not answers. If a two questions have the same answer they are not necessarily duplicates.

Comment: Never had problems with the razors but plenty of times with shaving cream even travel-sized ones.

Comment: @JoErNanO when I voted to close the question as a duplicate of [Can I bring a pack of razor blades on a plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/98311/19400) it *was* a duplicate question.  It's apparent from the edit history that earlier and later versions were broader, but version four was "Which shaving blades are permitted in carry on luggage?": essentially the same question.

Comment: @phoog But even in version 4, the questions in the body were "What's best practice here? How do frequent travelers usually deal with this issue?". The question in the title has been added by somebody else than OP.

Comment: Wow, there are still people shaving with tools like swords and machettes?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo [You'd be amazed.](https://youtu.be/JJksS4fCwMA)

Answer (score 28):

**Disposable/cartridge razors are universally permitted in carry-on luggage.** Here's the TSA on the topic: https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2010/08/17/safety-razors-and-disposable-razors

Comment: This is excellent!

Comment: That link is amazing. *This gentleman is shaving with a Samurai sword. No-go! (Swords must be checked with luggage)*

Comment: The page also states that an electric razor is OK.  That's what I prefer for travelling, since it doesn't require water/cleanup.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I was expecting him to hold that pose for about three seconds, and then have the top half of his head slide diagonally off.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to bring an **electric shaver**. While this won't give you the same clean shave as a proper razor blade, but in my opinion it's as least as good as those disposable ones. There are cheap (and lousy) travel shavers, but even the normal sized ones don't take up too much space in your carry-on luggage.

Answer (score 4):

I've researched this problem extensively and tried out every type of shavers out there. My current solution is to use the fantastic **[Philips OneBlade](https://www.usa.philips.com/c-m-pe/oneblade-face-style-shave)**:

[image]

It can obviously be taken as carry-on, works for a long time without recharging and is very lightweight. You cannot get a close shave with it, but it's amazingly gentle and won't cause any irritation even if you have extremely sensitive skin. It costs less than 50 Euros, so it's an easy purchase even if you're skeptical. There's also a "pro" model with fancy LED indicators, but it shaves exactly the same, so not worth the investment.

Answer (score 2):

tldr:

### Get the free one at your hotel

For me, good traveling generally means traveling with less stuff. The things I try to leave at home are soap, toothpaste, razors, and shave cream.

But wait - how do I stay clean? What about basic hygiene? Hotels "always" have soap, but what about toothpaste? In the US, most hotels will have "courtesy" packs. Specifically, most hotels will give you a complimentary razor, shave cream, and a toothpaste.

So call the hotel where you are traveling too, and ask them if they have complimentary razors. That will lighten your load, if just by a little bit.

If you are traveling on the cheap, like at a youth hostel, then probably skipping shaving is the way to go. I suggest continuing to brush teeth though, so bring a small tube of toothpaste.

Comment: "That will lighten your load, if just by a little bit." -- by about 7 grams, for a disposable twin-blade. So if you'll be gone long enough to grow a beard weighing more than 7 grams, it's worth taking the razor ;-).

Comment: @Pont Ha! Maybe I speak to colloquially; volume, packing time, and effort are included in the statement "lighten the load." IMO, the less you bring, the easier the travel. Perhaps I should ask a SE travel question about travel with zero luggage!

Comment: In many places (most of Europe for example), the majority of hotel rooms are in budget to medium hotels with far fewer freebies.  Expenses don't normally cover the ones you decsribe

Comment: This could be a good idea in general, but anyone with eczema or other issues with skin should be careful. Often the freebies at hotels (at least in the USA) are murder on bumpy or sensitive skin. I actually tried this once, and the soap left me itchy all day because of how dry I was. Very uncomfortable when sitting with a customer in a hot office. On the way back to the hotel I stopped at a Walgreens and bought some travel-sized items I should have bought in the first place.

Comment: +1 to Snowman.  It's not just the soap that's bad quality, but the razors themselves.

Comment: It does not hurt your teeth to brush without toothpaste for a couple of nights. If you are going for just a weekend, do not bother with toothpaste.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is applying a laser or IPL and remove your beard (semi-) permanently. I know depending on the cultures and preferences you are not willing to remove it altogether, but I'm quite satisifed with it.

You can get the treatment in a medical institute, but there is also a variety of products you can apply by yourself.

An example: [SMOOTHSKIN GOLD](https://www.smoothskin.com):

[image]

These products don't have a razor blade attached and you can bring them safely (but once you finish it, you don't need).